# String index out of range: -1 in dell boomi

Tags: boomi

I am getting This Error "String index out of range: -1". 
does this have something to do with the input data like any character or something?

Can anyone please explain me the root cause of this error and how do i resolve?

Comment: Share the sample  and complete error of your program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Suresh. we are good now. due to multiple line breaks this problem was occurring. we removed line space by field wise and able to resolve it.